# When using Templates in C++ how does the compiler know how many data-types to instantiate?

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, low-level

I just started learning Templates. How does the compiler know which data-types are required? Can someone please explain how compilers treat and work with templates?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Modern compilers are mostly based on black magic books (and applying the right spells) and deep crystal ball views. The unicorn league thoroughly helped about improvement directing to these basic technique in the recent decades. :-)

Comment: There are also [dragons](http://llvm.org/Logo.html) involved nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

It's based on actual instantiation. If you actually declare on object using one of your templates (and any given set of parameters to it), then code will be generated. A decent compiler will generate code for exactly those configurations that you use, and none for those you do not use.  I hope that explains it adequately.

Comment: A better compiler will fold identical implementations and methods into one (after possibly detecting to see if anyone takes a pointer to a method or the like).  [gcc gold linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29) or MSVC both do this.  And [clang gold linker](http://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html).

Comment: this means that the definition of the template usually have to be visible where its used, not just the declaration